# I have to create an exception that ignores string data from an int table

Tags: oracle

this is my first post here, so i would like to ask you some help. I'm supposed to get the average from a table with int data, but it also has string data. I need to create an exception that gets the avg ignoring the string datas

```
   create table x (y varchar(10));
    insert into x values (5);
    insert into x values (1);
    insert into x values (2);
    insert into x values (14);
    insert into x values (3);
    insert into x values ('a');
insert into x values ('asdds');
select avg(y) from x
```

Comment: Is this just a contrived exercise, because number columns should be defined as NUMBER type, not varchar2.

Comment: yeah that's the thing, i have to work with exceptions and functions and i'm confused

Answer (score 1):

Use `TO_NUMBER` as it will handle all valid numbers:

```sql
SELECT AVG(TO_NUMBER(y DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR)) As avg_y
FROM   x
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
create table x (y) AS
SELECT '5'      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '1e0'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- This is a valid number!
SELECT '2.0'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0.14e2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- So is this!
SELECT '3'      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'a'      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'assdds' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | AVG_Y |
> | --- |
> | 5 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=5fb942a68052db21750ff797441cef3b)*

Answer (score 0):

With data you posted, see if this helps:

```
SQL> select avg(y) from x
  2  where regexp_like(y, '^[[:digit:]]+$');

    AVG(Y)
----------
         5

SQL>
```